# Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[^/]+)/edit_post$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am going through a Django tutorial and getting this error when trying to open post_detail view ( where i put the link of of edit_post ) for edit post in my blog app. I use Django==3.1.2.

urls.py

```
path('<id>/edit_post', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
```

A template that causes the error in line 5 - post_detail_view.html. The error message highlights {% url 'edit_post' posts.id %}

post_detail_view.html

```
<br>
<a>{{ post.post_title }}</a>
<br>

 <a href="{% url 'mains:edit_post' post.id %}">Edit</a>
```

**The Problem**

When i open post_detail.html page in browser , i get this error :- Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/edit_post$'].
When i delete edit_post link from post_detail page then works fine but when i put the link of edit_post in post_detail and open it, This error is raising.
I am stuck with this problem and have no idea what is wrong.

**What have i tried.**

1). I have changed a link of Edit button.

2). I have replaced different view but again i changed it. AND it didn't work.

Help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help. Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Try to change to post.slug you have yours post.post_title, but in edit url {} you used posts.slug

Comment: You mean i should use :- post.post_title instead of post.slug

Comment: No I mean you have typo it should be post.slug not posts.slug

Comment: Thank you but i've changed it , the same error is raising.

Comment: Then most likely you have empty slug. Did you check your admin to see if the slug field is not empty?

Comment: But how, can you please instruct me ? I will appreciate it

Comment: I have not slugfield in any of my models.

Comment: What happens if you try this?  `<a href="{{post.slug}}/edit_post" >Edit</a>`

Comment: @Daniel it is opened but when i click on edit button , it raised :- Page not found (404)

Comment: if you do not have slug field, first try to use ```post.id```. Try this first to see if you can edit.

Comment: Can you inspect the href and show the link inside?

Comment: @Daniel  I have updated my question.

I have removed slug in everywhere and i have put id . But when i open it shows :- Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[^/]+)/edit_post$']

Comment: @ha-neul  I have updated my question.

I have removed slug in everywhere and i have put id . But when i open it shows :- Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[^/]+)/edit_post$']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my post_detail.html.

I should use data.id, instead of post.id. **Because all the objects in my post_detail.html was associated with data.id.**

```
<a href="{% url 'mains:edit_post' data.id %}">Edit</a>
```